# Activity overlapping on fragment in lollipop

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to call a simple `Fragment` from an `Activity`. It is working fine on pre-lollipop. But on lollipop device, the `Button` of the activity layout is overlapping with the fragment layout. Here is my code:

**`MyFragment`**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_myfragment,container,false);
}}
```

**`MainActivity`:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment, frag , "TagMy");
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Layout of **`MainActivity`:**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/main">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment">
     </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout of **`Fragment`**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000">
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a fragment container within you RelativeLayout main.

For you fragment container, use either a RelativeLayout or a FrameLayout.

In your XML, put the fragment container inside the main layout and after the Button and TextView. The reason for that is that when widgets occupy the same space (like in your case your button and fragment container), the last to appear in your XML file is on top of the other.

You should not use your main layout as fragment container.

EDIT : Once you have changed the XML file (using either a RelativeLayout or a FrameLayout as container), you need to update your FragmentTransaction to use this container:

```
transaction.add(R.id.fragment, frag , "TagMy");
```

Also I can see in your code that you created a Fragment in you XML file. I assume this is what you want to use as container. You shouldn't do this because you are mixing two methods of fragments : static and dynamic. If you set up Fragment in your XML, it is static and cannot be removed, but if you only set up a container in your XML and then instantiate fragments in your code using the FragmentManager (like you were doing) ; you are adding them dynamically.

So once again, use either a RelativeLayout or FrameLayout, but not Fragment as container. And update your FragmentTransaction. =)

Comment: Thanks for your time. But It did not solve the problem. I have updated my code. Please take a look. I am having this problem only in lollipop.

Comment: You did not change your FragmentTransaction code. You are still using your main layout as container. see my edited answer.

Comment: I have updated the code according to your suggestion but still getting the same problem. Please take a look.

Comment: I just created a quick project using your updated code and it's fine on lollipop (Android 5.0.1 API21) and other versions of Android. Now I'd say make sure your SDK is up to date cause I can't think of anything else. Let me know when you find the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JDenais.My SDK is up to date. I think there is some problem with my Genymotion lollipop emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you're certainly moved on already, but I just had the same problem you had and in my case, the button was overlapping the fragment because it had an Elevation.

Elevation only works in Lollipop as it is part of the Material Design introduced in Lollipop.

I'm just starting to play with it now.

So to answer your question, and if your problem is also due to elevation, you can either get rid of the elevation, or give a higher elevation to your fragment (set the elevation on the main layout of the fragment).

I hope it helped.

Comment: So, did it help, or was it something else ?